# Amazon Redshift : Fetch latest row query

Tags: amazon-redshift

saletable :

```
saleID | date | orderstatus | .....
```

I want to fetch only latest details for each saleID. I can do it using nested queries like

```
Select * from saletable t1 where date in ( select max(date) from saletable t2 where t1.saleID = t2.saleID )
```

Is it possible to do it with a simple query ? If so, any hint ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html) to do this efficiently:

```
WITH ld AS (
  SELECT saleID, max("date") AS latest FROM saletable GROUP BY saleID)
SELECT s.*
FROM saletable s
JOIN ld ON ld.saleID = s.saleID
WHERE s."date" = ld.latest;
```

As commented by DogBoneBlues: This has the advantage over the original method as there are only 2 scans of the data (one is aggregated and the other is filtered, both of which a columnar DB like Redshift will do very efficiently).  With the original approach, a query would be reissued for each row of the data resulting in an O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation.

Comment: Is the above query has any significance over the sub-query which I'd mentioned in the question?